# Is there a TQFT of links and their "cobordisms" (embedded surfaces in $S^3\times [0,1]$)?

Tags: mathematical-physics, geometric-topology, knot-theory, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory

Given two oriented links $K_1, K_2$ in $S^3$, it is an interesting problem to figure out whether there exists an oriented surface with boundary which is embedded (locally flatly) in $S\times [0,1]$ whose boundaries are exactly $K_1\times 0$ and $K_2\times 1$, considered as in- and out-boundary.

I found this notion very similar to the notion of cobordism. Of course in this formulation every link are "cobordant", but there is a restriction on the minimal genus of "cobordism" which depends on how the two links are "similar". (This notion is of course different from link concordance because we're allowing any surface, not just $K_1 \times [0,1]$.)

Just as with cobordisms between manifolds, I think it would be interesting if there is a topological quantum field theory (TQFT) for links and "cobordisms" as described above.

**Is there any such TQFT known?**

Comment: Knot Floer homology satisfies almost all of the axioms.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for the comment. Could you give me a brief explanation of how knot Floer homology fits into the framework of TQFT as described above?

Comment: I'm surprised that this question has so many favorites and so few upvotes.

Comment: Khovanov homology defines a projective TQFT. The morphisms are only defined up to sign. There are oriented models for Khovanov homology that resolve the sign, but are intractable. Rasmussen used Khovanov homology to prove the Milnor conjecture about the least genus surface a torus knot could bound in the 4 ball.